# Excel -- Tell whether a string contains any value in a table column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

## Background

I'm using Excel 2013.

I have an Excel table named `SiteCategories`, with a number of Category columns, and then sites in those columns, like so:

[image]

So we could get to those values using `=SiteCategories[Category1]`

I also have a list of URLs -- think full URLs such as `http://www.sitea.com/page/page.html`

## What I'd like to do

For that giant list of URLs, I'd like to have columns next to them, saying whether they're in category A or category B, like so:

[image]

I'd like the matching to be case-insensitive because the URLs aren't normalized. However, if it makes it easier, I can process the fields or wrap them in `lower()` though I imagine this process would be able to do that too.

## Where I'm stuck

I can do matches and searches on one piece of text, but I'm having trouble doing so on a range of text.

Essentially what I want to say is, if any piece of text in the given category column is found within the URL (in a case-insensitive fashion), then the URL is in that category.

However, most of the `MATCH` and `SEARCH` functions don't appear to easily support querying a range of values.

It seems like I want to do the opposite of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15566316/excel-finding-partial-text-in-range-return-an-index) -- whereas that solution uses a wildcard on one term to find it in multiple cells, I want to use multiple cell text as wildcards against one string and return true if any of them are true.

## How I'm doing it now

Currently, the formula I'm using is an `OR` statement are using a bunch of `SEARCH` formulas, like below (where `F3` is the cell with the URL):

```
=OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("sitea.com",F3)), ISNUMBER(SEARCH("siteb.com",F3)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("sitec.com",F3)), ISNUMBER(SEARCH("sited.com",F3)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("sitee.com",F3)))
```

However, this is a little untenable as the requirements for what sites go in what categories change over time. I'd like to be able to put those into a table to make them easily editable, hence the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an array formula entered with ctrl+shift+enter.   Search is not case sensitive so that should be fine.

```
=OR(IFERROR(SEARCH(SiteCategories[Category1],A2),0))
```

Here it is setup to handle blank lines in the table thanks to Kyle in the comments.

```
=OR(IFERROR(IF(SiteCategories[Category2]<>"",SEARCH(SiteCategories[Category2],A‌​2),0),0))
```

Comment: NICE! I was trying an array formula but wasn't wrapping it in `OR`. I'm going to test this out and then will likely mark it as the answer. Thanks! I really appreciate the help and the nice concise formula.

Comment: I'm running into one issue -- it seems that when I run this for the Category2 example above, which has some blank cells, it matches everything. Is there a way that I can use a structured table reference to only pull the columns that actually have data? Or do I need to wrap that in something?

Comment: @SeanKilleen this is @gtwebb's formula, accounting for blanks `=OR(IFERROR(IF(SiteCategories[Category2]<>"",SEARCH(SiteCategories[Category2],A2),0),0))`